# SQL Escape '#' Symbol

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-insert

I have a SQL query that inserts data to the database. 
Below is my sample data:

- OrderID: **1**
- Email: **#TestDistribution**

However, when I am trying to insert the `OrderID` and `Email` values to the table but the '**#**' cannot be read by SQL Server.

So that, how would I escape it?

I have an idea of apostrophe's can be escaped using `CHAR(29)` and what would be the equivalent for `#`?

Below is my query:

```
INSERT INTO orders(orderid,email) VALUES(1,'#TestDistribution')
```

Below is the table structure:

orders

- `orderid: int`
- `email: nchar(150)`

There is no error raised by the server, but upon checking the orders table, the data was not inserted.

Comment: Please show your insert statement.

Comment: Please post your INSERT query

Comment: What is the data type of your column email?

Comment: INSERT INTO orders(orderid,email) VALUES(1,'#TestDistribution')

Comment: I am using the **CHAR(35)** and still cannot get it.

Comment: Please post the actual code in the question, the `#` character has no special meaning and should not end up being a problem. And please be specific when describing the problem. "Cannot be read by SQL Server", what exactly does this mean? Are you actually getting a "Unclosed quotation mark after the caracter string '#TestDistribution'" ?

Comment: @lan - The problem is because you have Unclosed quotation mark after the character string. you can just remove the extra ' mark from your insert query and will just work fine.

Comment: @balaji Hi. Still the same :(

Comment: @lan - please post the table structure and insert query code in your question section.

Comment: @balaji please see updated question above. apologies. thanks

Comment: And we're telling you that this should work so there has to be more things to the problem that you're not telling us, most likely there are things happening you're not aware of, but nobody here can tell you what they are. Are you running it in a transaction that is subsequently rolled back? How are you verifying that the row was inserted or not? Try creating a [mcve], meaning a complete example that creates the table, adds the row and then selects it back out, and see if that works. If it does (and it should) you need to dig deeper in your application code.

Comment: @lan - It works perfectly fine here with the table structure and insert query that you have provided. As Lasse is pointing out we need look out for other things also.

Comment: When you run insert statement, do you get '1 row effected'? Also check for triggers on that table.

Comment: Sounds as if you are missing a commit in your code that does the insert

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for posting your answers here. The issue has been resolved already. I found out that there were some settings in my server which restricts special characters.

Apologies.

Thank you everyone!

Answer (score 1):

Works fine for me on `SQL Server 2008` using:

Create/Insert:

```
CREATE TABLE yourtable
    ([OrderID] int, [Email] nvarchar(99))
;

INSERT INTO yourtable
    ([OrderID], [Email])
VALUES
    (1, '#TestDistribution')
;
```

Select:

```
SELECT * FROM yourtable
```

Output:

```
OrderID Email
1       #TestDistribution
```

Comment: Hi. I'm using SQL Server 2008. Is this the same version as yours?

Comment: @IanSiñel Yes, to be more specific I tested it in SQL Server 2008 R2 10.50.4000.0

Answer (score 1):

you'vve got two ' a the end

try

```
 INSERT INTO orders(orderid,email) VALUES(1,'#TestDistribution')
```

Comment: I still get the same output. Data wasn't inserted.

Comment: what happens if you remove the #?  Is the # definitely the problem ?Are those the only fields in your table?  Do  fields need to be populated with non null data?  maybe show us the CREATE TABLE for your table

Comment: Have you proved that the # is the problem, is an important question - if it is # that is the problem, then changing # to X would presumably stop the error - that isn't a fix, it's an experiment- have you tried this?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your column type should be varchar

```
create table orders(orderid int(30),email varchar(30));
insert into orders value(1,'#TestDistribution');
select * from orders;
```